# "Class \Drupal\rsvplist\Controller\ReportController does not exist"

Tags: 8, drush

I'm following [this Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrvLnhm6Rqw&list=PLpVC00PAQQxHi-llE9Z8-Q747NYWpsq6t&index=32) to get a better grasp of module development, and I am not understanding the error I'm getting in my cli when flushing my caches. I've created an extension of ControllerBase called ReportController, but it tells me that this class doesn't exist. Sorry if this is a stupid newbie question.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
/**
* @file
* Contains \Drupal\rsvplist\Controller\ReportController
*/

namespace Drupal\rsvplist\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;

/**
* Controller for RSVP List Report
*/
class ReportController extends ControllerBase {
  /**
  *Gets all RSVPs for all nodes
  *
  * @return array
  */
  protected function load() {
    $select = Database::getConnection()->select('rsvplist','r');
    // Join the users table, so we can get the entry creator's username
    $select->join('users_field_data','u','r.uid = u.uid');
    // Join the node table, so we can get the event's name.
    $select->join('node_field_data','n','r.nid=n.nid');
    // Select these specific fields for the output
    $select->addField('u','name','username');
    $select->addField('n','title');
    $select->addField('r','mail');
    $entries = $select->execute()->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $entries;
  }

  /**
  * Created the report page
  *
  * @return array
  * Render array for report output
  */
  public function report() {
    $content = array();
    $content['message'] = array(
      '#markup'=>$this->t('Below is a list of all Event RSVPs including username, email address and the name of the event they will be attending.'),
    );
    $headers = array(
      t('Name'),
      t('Event'),
      t('Email')
    );
    $rows = array();
    foreach (entries = $this->load() as $entry) {
      // Santiize each entry
      $rows[] = array_map('Drupal\Component\Utility\SafeMarkup::checkPlain', $entry);

    }
    $content['table'] = array(
      '#type'=>'table',
      '#header'=>$headers,
      '#rows'=>$rows,
      '#empty'=>t('No entries available.'),
    );
    // Don't cache this page.
    $content['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
    return $content;
  }
}
```

Here are my routing and links .yml files if you'd also like to see those:

```
rsvplist.admin_settings:
  path: '/admin/config/content/rsvplist'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\rsvplist\Form\RSVPSettingsForm'
    _title: 'RSVP List Settings'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer rsvplist'

rsvplist.report:
  path: '/admin/reports/rsvplist'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\rsvplist\Controller\ReportController::report'
    _title: 'List of RSVPs'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'view rsvplist'
```

rsvplist.links.menu.yml

```
rsvplist.report:
  title: 'List of RSVP submissions'
  description: 'View listing of RSVPs'
  route_name: rsvplist.report
  parent: system.admin_reports
  weight: 0
```

Finally, here's what happens on my cli when I run `drush cr`:

```
ReflectionException: Class \Drupal\rsvplist\Controller\ReportController does not exist in                                                                             [error]
/Users/myname/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8.9.1/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityResolverManager.php:136
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/myname/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8.9.1/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityResolverManager.php(136): ReflectionMethod->__construct('\\Drupal\\rsvplis...',
'report')
#1 /Users/myname/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8.9.1/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityResolverManager.php(221):
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityResolverManager->setParametersFromReflection(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\Routing\Route))
#2 /Users/me/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8.9.1/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EntityRouteAlterSubscriber.php(48):
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityResolverManager->setRouteOptions(Object(Symfony\Component\Routing\Route))
#3 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EntityRouteAlterSubscriber->onRoutingRouteAlterSetType(Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuildEvent),
'routing.route_a...', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#4 /Users/myname/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8.9.1/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(111): call_user_func(Array,
Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuildEvent), 'routing.route_a...', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#5 /Users/myname/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8.9.1/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteBuilder.php(189):
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('routing.route_a...', Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuildEvent))
#6 /Users/myname/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8.9.1/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Routing/RouteBuilder.php(83): Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild()
#7 /Users/myname/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8.9.1/core/includes/common.inc(1090): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild()
#8 /Users/myname/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8.9.1/core/includes/utility.inc(55): drupal_flush_all_caches()
#9 /Applications/DevDesktop/tools/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/cache.drush.inc(302): drupal_rebuild(Object(Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader),
Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#10 /Applications/DevDesktop/tools/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(422): drush_cache_rebuild()
#11 /Applications/DevDesktop/tools/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#12 /Applications/DevDesktop/tools/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command()
#13 /Applications/DevDesktop/tools/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#14 /Applications/DevDesktop/tools/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#15 /Applications/DevDesktop/tools/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(12): drush_main()
#16 {main}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've re-read my code over and over again and I don't see any issues.

Comment: You didn't mention where exactly you were placing the named files. Inside what folders. For the controller the path needs to be `/modules/custom/rsvplist/src/Controller/ReportController.php`. For the form it needs to be `/modules/custom/rsvplist/src/Form/RSVPSettingsForm.php`.

Comment: What's the filepath to the file reported as not missing?

Comment: @leymannx okay yep, I put my Controller folder in the wrong place. stupid me. thank you for the help!